# I am trying to manually serialize an android.Bundle. Any thoughts on the implementation?

Tags: java, android

I wrote this because I need to store an unknown bundle to a database.  Most everyone suggested to `Parcel` it.  The problem is the android docs specifically say not to use `parcel` for persistent storage.  With some help from `palacsint` I was able to refactor my original code to the following:

```
public class AndroidBundleSerializer {

    public final Map<String, DataTypeHandler> dataTypeHandlers;

    public AndroidBundleSerializer() {
        final Map<String, DataTypeHandler> dataTypeHandlers =
                             new HashMap<String, DataTypeHandler>();

    register(dataTypeHandlers, new BooleanHandler());
    register(dataTypeHandlers, new BooleanArrayHandler());
              // Register other handlers here
    this.dataTypeHandlers = Collections.unmodifiableMap(dataTypeHandlers);
}
private void register(final Map<String, DataTypeHandler> dataTypeHandlers,
        final DataTypeHandler type) {
    final String name = type.getName();
    dataTypeHandlers.put(name, type);
} 
public interface DataTypeHandler {
    String getName();
    void write(ObjectOutputStream out, Bundle bundle, String key) throws IOException;
    void read(ObjectInputStream in, Bundle bundle, String key) throws IOException;
}
private final static String TYPE_BOOLEAN = "Boolean";
private final static String TYPE_BOOLEAN_ARRAY = "boolean.array";
private final static String TYPE_STRING_ARRAY = "String.array";
private final static String TYPE_STRING_ARRAY_LIST = "String.array.list";




    private class StringArrayHandler implements DataTypeHandler {
    public StringArrayHandler() {
    }
    public String getName() {
        return TYPE_STRING_ARRAY;
    }
    public void write(final ObjectOutputStream out, final Bundle bundle,
                        final String key) throws IOException {
        final String[] array = bundle.getStringArray(key);
        out.writeInt(array.length);
        for (String item : array) out.writeUTF(item);
        Log.v("SERIALIZE", key + "[" + getName() + "][" + array.length + "]");
    }
    public void read(final ObjectInputStream in, final Bundle bundle,
                        final String key) throws IOException {
        final int length = in.readInt();
        final String[] data = new String[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) data[i] = in.readUTF();
        bundle.putStringArray(key, data);
        Log.v("DE-SERIALIZE", key + "[" + getName() + "][" + length + "]");
    }
}

private class StringArrayListHandler implements DataTypeHandler {
    public StringArrayListHandler() {
    }
    public String getName() {
        return TYPE_STRING_ARRAY_LIST;
    }
    public void write(final ObjectOutputStream out, final Bundle bundle,
                        final String key) throws IOException {
        final String[] array = (String[]) bundle.getStringArrayList(key).toArray();
        out.writeInt(array.length);
        for (String item : array) out.writeUTF(item);
        Log.v("SERIALIZE", key + "[" + getName() + "][" + array.length + "]");
    }
    public void read(final ObjectInputStream in, final Bundle bundle,
                        final String key) throws IOException {
        final int length = in.readInt();
        final ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) data.add(in.readUTF());
        bundle.putStringArrayList(key, data);
        Log.v("DE-SERIALIZE", key + "[" + getName() + "][" + length + "]");
    }
}
```

And here is the code (in my SQLiteDataBaseManager class) that serializes the bundle:

```
private byte[] bundleToByteArray(Bundle bundle){
    AndroidBundleSerializer serializer = new AndroidBundleSerializer();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        for (final String key: bundle.keySet())  {
            final Object obj = bundle.get(key);
            String type = obj.getClass().getSimpleName();
            if(obj.getClass().isArray()) type = type + ".array";
            out.writeUTF(key);
            out.writeUTF(type);
            final DataTypeHandler dataTypeHandler = serializer.dataTypeHandlers.get(type);
            if (dataTypeHandler != null) {
                dataTypeHandler.write(out, bundle, key);
            } else {
                Log.v("DEBUG", key + "[" + type + "]");
            }
        }
        byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray();
        return buffer;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.i("BundleToByteArray","IOException");
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have a couple of questions regarding the above code.

1. Does anyone see any oportunites to improve this code.  I found it very repetative to write (I believe this is often an indicator that refactoring would help).
2. I have 21 posible types that could be in the bundle.  I have included code for 2 handlers (StringArray and StringArrayList that are almost identical.  Does anyone see any way to do away with all this boiler plate code and combining similar handlers.

Comment: Could you edit the question in a way that does not make existing answers meaningless, please? I think it would be better to ask a new question with the refactored code. Maybe somebody has another idea for the original question especially if you link it from the new one.



http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94446/editing-a-question-and-asking-a-completely-different-question

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64459/rolling-back-a-completely-changed-question

Comment: There is a PersistableBundle class in Android. There might be something useful there, though I haven't checked.

Answer (score 3):

1. Try to minimize the scope of local variables. It's not necessary to declare them at the beginning of the method, declare them where they are first used.

   See *Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables*. (Google for "minimize the scope of local variables", it's on Google Books too.))
2. You could replace the `Iterator` and the `while` loop with a [foreach loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html):

   ```
   for (final String key: bundle.keySet())
   ```
3. The same `if-else` structure is repeating in both methods. It's not too safe and error-prone since there is no compile time check that you provided both serialize and deserialize logic for the same type. You should replace them with polymorphism. Here is a common interface for every data type:

   ```
   public interface DataTypeHandler {

       String getName();

       void write(ObjectOutputStream out, Bundle bundle, String key) throws IOException;

       void read(ObjectInputStream in, Bundle bundle, String key) throws IOException;
   }
   ```

   A sample implementation for the `boolean[]` type:

   ```
   public class BooleanArrayHandler implements DataTypeHandler {

       public BooleanArrayHandler() {
       }

       @Override
       public String getName() {
           return "boolean.array";
       }

       @Override
       public void write(final ObjectOutputStream out, final Bundle bundle, 
               final String key) throws IOException {
           final boolean[] array = (boolean[]) bundle.get(key);
           final int len = array.length;
           out.writeInt(len);
           for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
               out.writeBoolean(array[i]);
           }
           Log.v("SERIALIZE", key + "[" + getName() + "][" + len + "]");
       }

       @Override
       public void read(final ObjectInputStream in, final Bundle bundle, 
               final String key) throws IOException {
           final int length = in.readInt();
           final boolean[] data = new boolean[length];
           for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
               data[i] = in.readBoolean();
           }
           bundle.putBooleanArray(key, data);
           Log.v("DE-SERIALIZE", key + "[" + getName() + "][" + length + "]");
       }
   }
   ```

   The code won't compile if you don't implement both `read` and `write` methods.

   Here is a constructor which fills a map with the available handler objects:

   ```
   private final Map<String, DataTypeHandler> dataTypeHandlers;

   public AndroidBundleSerializer() {
       final Map<String, DataTypeHandler> dataTypeHandlers = 
           new HashMap<String, DataTypeHandler>();
       register(dataTypeHandlers, new BooleanHandler());
       register(dataTypeHandlers, new BooleanArrayHandler());
       // ... more register calls here
       this.dataTypeHandlers = Collections.unmodifiableMap(dataTypeHandlers);
   }

   private void register(final Map<String, DataTypeHandler> dataTypeHandlers, 
           final DataTypeHandler type) {
       final String name = type.getName();
       dataTypeHandlers.put(name, type);
   }
   ```

   And the code which uses it for writing and replaces the one of big `if-else` conditionals:

   ```
   final DataTypeHandler dataTypeHandler = dataTypeHandlers.get(type);
   if (dataTypeHandler != null) {
       dataTypeHandler.write(out, bundle, key);
   } else {
       Log.v("DEBUG", key + "[" + type + "]");
   }
   ```

   The replacement of the read `if-else` conditionals should be similar.

   References:

   - *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by *Martin Fowler*: *Replacing the Conditional Logic on Price Code with Polymorphism*
   - [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Item 1 I will have to try out.  Its been a while since I hashed this out.  I remember moving them up there as there was an error (I think it was due to the try block).  Item 2: definitly.  I am new to java so I wasn't aware of this construct.  Item 3:  This one is going to take some research.  I will update my code when I get a minute to look at this.  Thanks again for the input.

Comment: Ok... I have implemented your suggestions (see edited question). Did I miss anything?

Comment: @cstrutton: I'll check it soon.

Answer (score 0):

For the update:

1. ```
   private final static String TYPE_BOOLEAN = "Boolean";
   private final static String TYPE_BOOLEAN_ARRAY = "boolean.array";
   private final static String TYPE_STRING_ARRAY = "String.array";
   private final static String TYPE_STRING_ARRAY_LIST = "String.array.list";
   ```

   These constants are useful during the refactoring but as far as I see, since their values are used only once, I'd remove them and use their values inside the `getName()` methods.
2. ```
   for (String item : array) out.writeUTF(item);
   ```

   According to the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language, 7.5 for Statements](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#454) you should use braces here. Omitting braces is error-prone.
3. ```
   final ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
   ```

   It's type could and should be simply `List<String>`:

   ```
   final List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
   ```

   Reference: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*
4. ```
   Log.v("DEBUG", key + "[" + type + "]");
   ```

   A more detailed log could be more useful here. Furthermore, if the loop found an unknown data type would it be worth to continue the serialization? I don't think so. I'd consider throwing an exception here to stop the whole processing.
5. Log calls from the `read` and `write` methods could be moved out to the `bundleToByteArray` method if you don't need to log the length.
6. Maybe reflection could help to reduce the number of classes to a couple of classes: one for handling simple types, one for lists and one for arrays.